# Vector products

Tags: vectors

Vectors a, b and c are present.

Given $a+b+c=0$, show that $a\times b=b \times c= c\times a$

I have tried starting from $a+b=-c$ and $a+c=-b$

then $-b \times -c=(a+c)(a+b)$

But somehow its not making sense.

How does one prove it?

Comment: Hint: find something to multiply both sides of $a+b+c=0$ which would reduce it to two terms.

Comment: Well, these three cross products are simply twice the (oriented) area of the triangle formed by $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $a\times (- a) =0$ and $-a=b+c$, one can get 
$$a\times (b+c)=0,$$
i.e., $a\times b=-a\times c=c\times a$. The other equality can be proved similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$$
a+b+c=o \Rightarrow a+b=-c \Rightarrow (a+b)\times a=-c\times a \Rightarrow b\times a=a\times c \Rightarrow a\times b=c\times a
$$
Can you figure out the rest ?

Comment: $-c \times a = a \times c$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I know $-c$ and $c$ only similar in scalar but with different directions, but how is it possible?

Comment: I suggest you study carefully the definition of the vector product. Changing the order of the terms changes the direction and thus the sign of the result.